# Overcome 255 char limitations in Sybase ASE system while Concat Multiple Column

Tags: concatenation, multiple-columns, sybase, truncated

I have a table with 39 column and 30 rows in Sybase.I am trying to Concat all the 39 columns in a single column with 30 rows.

Tools used:
Winsql professional 4.5  connect to Sybase DB

1. table1 has actual data
2. Created a temp table2 of data type text. Create table #temp2 (Line text)
3. Insert and formatted using trim for space,null values and tried concat using + symbol into temp table2 from table1

Result: data gets truncated at 256 char

Findings: Sybase ASE text data type supports only 255 char

Can someone suggest on how to overcome with this issue!

Comment: ASE `text` column has a 2GB limit; as Richard's alluded to, the issue (data truncation) is likely related to a) the front-end tool you're using, b) session settings ... and/or c) the query you're using (but haven't posted) that inserts the data into table2

Answer (score 0):

Sybase ASE's text data type is not limited to 256 characters, but there are some tricks to using it successfully such as specifying textsize and being aware that these settings may be session and stored procedure specific.

Consider the following example Sybase ASE 16.0 GA on Linux:

Create then 39 column table.

```sql
    create table table_1 (      
    col_1   Varchar(255)    null,
    col_2   Varchar(255)    null,
    col_3   Varchar(255)    null,
    col_4   Varchar(255)    null,
    col_5   Varchar(255)    null,
    col_6   Varchar(255)    null,
    col_7   Varchar(255)    null,
    col_8   Varchar(255)    null,
    col_9   Varchar(255)    null,
    col_10  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_11  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_12  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_13  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_14  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_15  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_16  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_17  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_18  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_19  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_20  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_21  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_22  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_23  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_24  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_25  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_26  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_27  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_28  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_29  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_30  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_31  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_32  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_33  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_34  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_35  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_36  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_37  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_38  Varchar(255)    null,
    col_39  Varchar(255)    null)
    go
```

I receive a warning about the potential row sizes not fitting on the page. My Sybase ASE instance is configured for 2K pages. 16K page size instances will not receive this warning. Truncation will only occur should the row size become larger than the page size:

```
Warning: Row size (10028 bytes) could exceed row size limit, which is 1962
bytes.
```

Insert the rows into table_1. Ideally, with 16K pages and columns with 255 characters, this insert statement could be used:

```sql
    insert into table_1 values (
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL01',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL02',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL03',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL04',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL05',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL06',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL07',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL08',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL09',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL10',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL11',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL12',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL13',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL14',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL15',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL16',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL17',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL18',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL19',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL20',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL21',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL22',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL23',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL24',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL25',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL26',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL27',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL28',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL29',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL30',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL31',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL32',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL33',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL34',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL35',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL36',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL37',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL38',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL39')
    go 30
```

The "go 30" at the end, submits the SQL batch 30 times, inserting 30 rows.

Since my own instance only has 2K pages, I'm limiting myself to 45 characters per column which is 1755 characters.

```sql
    insert into table_1 values (
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL01',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL02',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL03',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL04',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL05',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL06',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL07',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL08',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL09',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL10',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL11',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL12',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL13',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL14',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL15',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL16',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL17',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL18',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL19',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL20',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL21',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL22',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL23',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL24',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL25',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL26',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL27',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL28',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL29',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL30',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL31',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL32',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL33',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL34',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL35',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL36',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL37',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL38',
    '0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL39')
    go 30
```

Check the correct number of characters have been entered, this should be the length of string in each column. In my own case, 45.

```sql
    select
            char_length(col_1),
            char_length(col_2),
            char_length(col_3),
            char_length(col_4),
            char_length(col_5),
            char_length(col_6),
            char_length(col_7),
            char_length(col_8),
            char_length(col_9),
            char_length(col_10),
            char_length(col_11),
            char_length(col_12),
            char_length(col_13),
            char_length(col_14),
            char_length(col_15),
            char_length(col_16),
            char_length(col_17),
            char_length(col_18),
            char_length(col_19),
            char_length(col_20),
            char_length(col_21),
            char_length(col_22),
            char_length(col_23),
            char_length(col_24),
            char_length(col_25),
            char_length(col_26),
            char_length(col_27),
            char_length(col_28),
            char_length(col_29),
            char_length(col_30),
            char_length(col_31),
            char_length(col_32),
            char_length(col_33),
            char_length(col_34),
            char_length(col_35),
            char_length(col_36),
            char_length(col_37),
            char_length(col_38),
            char_length(col_39)
        from table_1
    go
```

Now create table_2 with the text column.

```sql
    create table table_2 (col_1 text null)
    go
```

Insert the rows into table_2 from the concatenated values of the columns in table_1. There will be one row in table_2 for each row in table_1.

```sql
    insert into table_2 select
            col_1 + 
            col_2 + 
            col_3 + 
            col_4 + 
            col_5 + 
            col_6 + 
            col_7 + 
            col_8 + 
            col_9 + 
            col_10 + 
            col_11 + 
            col_12 + 
            col_13 + 
            col_14 + 
            col_15 + 
            col_16 + 
            col_17 + 
            col_18 + 
            col_19 + 
            col_20 + 
            col_21 + 
            col_22 + 
            col_23 + 
            col_24 + 
            col_25 + 
            col_26 + 
            col_27 + 
            col_28 + 
            col_29 + 
            col_30 + 
            col_31 + 
            col_32 + 
            col_33 + 
            col_34 + 
            col_35 + 
            col_36 + 
            col_37 + 
            col_38 + 
            col_39 as result
    from table_1
    go
```

Check the length of the column in table_2. If using 45 characters it should be 1755; if using 255 characters it should be 9945.

```sql
    select char_length(col_1) from table_2
    go
```

Confirm the last value of the last row ends in "COL39".

```sql
    select col_1 from table_2
    go
```

Something like...

```
0123456789012345678901234567890123456789COL39
```

Given the above test case was conducted using Sybase's isql utility we can show that Sybase ASE does correctly concatenate the values and store them in a text column. You are using "winsql", a tool that I am not familiar with nor do I have access to. I imagine this may be imposing some limits on what is being displayed. I suspect somewhere it maybe running:

```sql
set textsize 255
```

or simply truncating the data. The above test case should be able to confirm this. The values returned by char_length() will not be subjected to the truncation unless the input data is truncated.

After installing Sybase ASE 12.5.1 on Windows 2000 and configuring it for 16K pages, the commands above were executed in a database called "rwc". The commands worked as advertised.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, we could not overcome the issue as the Sybase version seems to be very old.

Further with an alternative ,i decided using BCP utility tool on a stored proc.However my syntax had failed stating the below error

Procedure 'xp_cmdshell', Line 2:
> Can't open a connection to site 'Test_XP'.  See the error log file in
> the
> SQL Server boot directory.

When i checked the logs,

09 kernel  XP Server failed to start. Try bringing up XP Server manually. Check SQL Server documentation for more information 

Any Suggestions to use this BCP alternative on SP???

Comment: Can you inform us of the version Sybase ASE you're using `select @@version` and the logical page size `select @@maxpagesize`

Comment: You may need to configure the XP server in the interfaces file, the name used will probably be Test_XP. The XP server is not something normally used because it executes commands in the operating system.

Comment: Version is below 12.5.1....select @@maxpagesize  shows an error Must declare variable @@maxpagesize.

Comment: @BharathiSivam. I have built a Sybase ASE 12.5.1 on Windows 2000 with 16K pages and script works as advertised. I will update my answer with a screen shot of the result.